# Getting connection refused exception with HttpCilent but not when HttpsURLConnection is used

Tags: java, apache, http

I am getting connection refused exception when i am using the `HttpClient` to send the request but connection is established when i used the `HttpUrlConnection`. I want to use `HttpClient` but not able to figure out what is the reason for connection refusement as same thing works well when i use `HttpUrlConnection`.

Code when i use `HttpClient`

```
public static String httpGet(String urlStr) throws IOException {

    HttpClient conn = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(urlStr);
    HttpResponse response = conn.execute(request);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

    // Buffer the result into a string
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent())
    );
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line);
    }
    rd.close();
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Code when i use `HttpUrlConnection`

```
public static String httpGet(String urlStr) throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL(urlStr);
    HttpsURLConnection conn =
         (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    System.out.println("connection"+conn.getResponseCode());

    if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
        throw new IOException(conn.getResponseMessage());
    }

    // Buffer the result into a string
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
          new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream())
    );
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line);
    }
    rd.close();

    conn.disconnect();
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Which line / call throws the exception?

Comment: @Gimby I am gettin this exception when use HttpClient org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException : Connection to 'url' failed :Connection refused: connect

Comment: And what is the value of the URL in each case? and where is the evidence that they are the same?

Comment: i think my problem might be sending a https request to HttpClient